# Display a Different Set of Attributes for a Category in Front End

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, category-attribute

I need to display only relevant attributes for products in Front End. In my case, almost all categories are similar, but there are a couple of categories which have a few more attribute to be displayed that are relevant to them.

Example:

Attributes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

In front end:
For a Product 'AB234' in 'A' category display 1, 2, 3, 4
For a Product 'AB235' in 'B' category display 1, 5, 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, I have written an OS module that will perform very similarly to what you are needing. The only difference is that you exclude attributes from the category, instead of choosing which ones to use:

https://github.com/SwiftOtter/Modules

It is the `SwiftOtter_Attribute` module.

Comment: Thanks alot... SwitfOtter Studios ... Was exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your time and Help.

Comment: That's why the repo is there. I'm glad it helped!